# Assignment of variadic function fails with incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, tdd

I'm using ceedling with the 'fake funcion framework'([fff](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff/blob/master/fff.h)).

I declare a custom fake for my debug_printf function.

My debug.h

```
#ifndef DEBUG_H
#define DEBUG_H

void debug_printf(const char*, ...);

#endif // DEBUG_H
```

My some.h

```
#ifndef SOME_H
#define SOME_H

void f(void);

#endif // SOME_H
```

My some.c

```
#include "some.h"

#include "debug.h"

void f()
{
  debug_printf("test");
}
```

My test_some.c

```
#include "fff.h"

#include "some.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;

FAKE_VOID_FUNC2_VARARG(debug_printf, const char*, ...);

void debug_printf_custom(const char* fmt, ...)
{
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, fmt);
  vprintf(fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
}

void test_f(void)
{
  debug_printf_fake.custom_fake = debug_printf_custom;
  f();
}

int main(void)
{
  test_f();
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the test I've got the message:

```
> gcc test_some.c some.c -o test

test_some.c: In function ‘test_f’:
test_some.c:23:35: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     debug_printf_fake.custom_fake = debug_printf_custom;
                                   ^
```

What should I change to get the correct pointer type.

Comment: Your code is not complete.  For example, what 's `FAKE_VOID_FUNC2_VARARG`?  Post your **complete** code.

Comment: I just update my complete code with some automatic created mock files from ceedling.

Comment: Nope it still lacks a [mre]

Comment: Just updated to a basic minimal example. Add missing some.c.

Comment: I guess you should change `debug_printf_custom` to use a `va_list` parameter.

Comment: Yes, just hit this also. I'm checking my "ceedling" test. The minimal example will work with this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got all together.

First of all:

```
void debug_printf_custom(const char* fmt, ...)
{
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, fmt);
  vprintf(fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
}
```

must be

```
void debug_printf_custom(const char* fmt, va_list ap)
{
  vprintf(fmt, ap);
}
```

as pointed by @ianabbott.

Unfortunately the minimal example will work, but not the one with Ceedling.
The solution when using the [fff-plugin](https://github.com/ElectronVector/fake_function_framework) from ElectronVector.

The fff.h is outdated and should be updated. 
In your project folder:

```
cd vendor/ceedling/plugins/fake_function_framework/vendor/fff 
git fetch
git checkout master
```